# Remover um elemento de um array em JAVA

Tags: java

Estou a começar a Programar com objetos. Criei um método para apagar elementos de um array através de um arrayCopy mas não sei como fazer com que os meus arrays de objetos usem esse método. O Erro que dá é que não posso converter Object[] em Caixa[]. A única solução que sei até ao momento seria criar um método removerElemento() para cada tido de Objeto mas não queria isso, preferia não repetir o código.

```
private static void escolherQualApagar() {
    System.out.println("Insira o tipo de figura que quer apagar:  [caixa, cone, cilindro, esfera] ");
    String resposta = Le.umaString();
    switch (resposta) {
        case "caixa":

            System.out.println("Caixas: " + Arrays.toString(Caixas));

            System.out.println("qual destas figuras deseja apagar? ");

            int indiceCaixa = Le.umInt();

            if (Caixas == null || indiceCaixa < 0 || indiceCaixa >= Caixas.length) {
                System.out.println("Não é possivel efetuar nenhuma operação!");
            }
            
            
            Caixas = removerElemento(Caixas, indiceCaixa);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Caixas));

            break;

        case "cone":
            System.out.println("Cones: " + Arrays.toString(Cones));

            System.out.println("qual destas figuras deseja apagar? ");

            int indiceCone = Le.umInt();

            if (Cones == null || indiceCone < 0 || indiceCone >= Cones.length) {
                System.out.println("Não é possivel efetuar nenhuma operação!");
            }

            Cones = removerElemento(Cones, indiceCone);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Cones));
            break;

        case "cilindro":
            System.out.println("Cilindro: " + Arrays.toString(Cilindros));

            System.out.println("qual destas figuras deseja apagar? ");

            int indiceCilindro = Le.umInt();

            if (Cilindros == null || indiceCilindro < 0 || indiceCilindro >= Cilindros.length) {
                System.out.println("Não é possivel efetuar nenhuma operação!");
            }

            Cilindros = removerElemento(Cilindros, indiceCilindro);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Cilindros));
            break;

        case "esfera":
            System.out.println("Esfera: " + Arrays.toString(Esferas));
            System.out.println("qual destas figuras deseja apagar? ");

            int indiceEsfera = Le.umInt();

            if (Esferas == null || indiceEsfera < 0 || indiceEsfera >= Esferas.length) {
                System.out.println("Não é possivel efetuar nenhuma operação!");
            }

            Esferas = removerElemento(Esferas, indiceEsfera);
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Esferas));
            break;
    }

}

private static Object[] removerElemento(Object[] arr, int index) {
    Object[] result = new Object[arr.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, 0, index);
    if (arr.length != index) {
        System.arraycopy(arr, index + 1, result, index, arr.length - index - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar os generics, para isso, basta alterar o método "removerElemento". Segue o meu exemplo:

```
private static <T> T[] removerElemento(T[] array, int indice) {
    if (array == null || indice < 0 || indice >= array.length) {
        return array;
    }
    
    T[] novoArray = (T[]) Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length - 1);
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, novoArray, 0, indice);
    System.arraycopy(array, indice + 1, novoArray, indice, array.length - indice - 1);
    
    return novoArray;
}
```

Depois basta utilizar o método removerElemento para remover os elementos que você quiser, conforme exemplo:

```
Caixas = removerElemento(Caixas, indiceCaixa);
Cones = removerElemento(Cones, indiceCone);
```